# Solving a 2nd-order system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

How does one solve a system of ODEs of the type
$$ \ddot{x}=Ax $$
without reducing it to a system of four 1st-order equations?

Comment: How about good old ansatz $v e^{\lambda t}$? Should work if $A$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, bring $A$ into Jordan normal form $A=T^{-1}JT$. Then using $y=Tx$ the equation transforms to $\ddot y= Jy$ and you can treat each Jordan block separately. If the dimension is $1$, then $\ddot y=λy$ has a standard solution. For blocks of higher dimension you get coupled equations, for instance in dimension 2
\begin{align}
\ddot y_1&=λy_1+y_2\\
\ddot y_2&=λy_2
\end{align}
that can be solved in reverse order.